# Ruby on Rails testing password presence fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to test that password should be present for a user signup. 
In my test:

```
def setup
  @user = User.new(name: "foobar", email: "foobar@gmail.com",
                 password: 'password',
                 password_confirmation: 'password')
end

test "password can't be blank" do
  @user.password = nil
  assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

User model:

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format:  { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}

has_secure_password
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 8}
```

this test passes fine, but if I change it to @user.password = "", the test fails. Could anyone help me understand why? what is the difference here for password? For emails, i used "" and it worked fine.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you put in your `User` model so we can see your validations?

Comment: Sorry i have now added the User model

Answer (score 0):

The test for `@user.email = ""`, passes because even you don't specify minimum length validation you have regex validation.

> VALID_EMAIL_REGEX =
>   /\A[\w+-.]+@[a-z\d-]+(.[a-z\d-]+)*.[a-z]+\z/i.

For password, you have minimum length validation, so `@user.password = ""` should also pass the test.

Comment: but my problem is `@user.password = ""` didn't pass the test but `@user.password = nil` passed. So I have no idea what the differences are for these two.. And why one passed not the other

Comment: Sorry I can't figure out the reason why `@user.password = ""` didn't pass the test. You have taken care of this by two conditions `presence: true` and `length: { minimum: 8 }`. You can check in the application by entering password as `""` and see the user gets created or not. Also `nil` belongs Nil class whereas `""` belong to string(empty string).